# Realign Multiple Select Options on Mobile screen

Tags: javascript, css

I have 4 Select options set to `width: 21%`;

This works great on Desktop as they are all aligned horrizontally but stay the same on mobile where the size of the SELECT's decrease, remain horizontal aligned and you cant make out the text in them.

How can I have the select options aligned horrizontal on desktop and vertical (one on top of another) on smaller screens?

I could change the `width: 21%;` to `width: 260px;` but is there a better method?

```js
function filter() {
  var filter_num_package = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase().trim();
  var filter_num_nights = document.getElementById("myInput1").value.toUpperCase().trim();

  var filter_num_people = document.getElementById("myInput2").value.toUpperCase().trim();
  //loop through tr
  $(" tbody tr").each(function() {
    //get td value 0,1,2
    var first_td = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().toUpperCase().trim()
    var second_td = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase().trim()
    var third_td = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text().toUpperCase().trim()

    //check if value matches
    if (first_td.includes(filter_num_package) &&
      second_td.includes(filter_num_nights) &&
      third_td.includes(filter_num_people)) {
      //display that row
      $(this).css("display", "");
    } else {
      //hide that row
      $(this).css("display", "none");
    }
  })
}

function filter1() {
  //get value of last select
  var values = document.getElementById("myInput3").value.toUpperCase().trim();
  //check if value is not both or first option
  if (values != "BOTH" && values != "") {
    //hide all td which are greater then 4
    $("tr").find("td:gt(4)").hide()
    //loop through second tr > th
    $("table tr:eq(1) th ").each(function() {
      //check if the text is equal to selct value
      if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().trim() === values) {
        //show that th
        $(this).show();
        //get class 21,22..etc
        var class_to_hide = $(this).attr('class');
        //check th has value 21,22..etc remove colspan
        $("tr").find("th:contains(" + class_to_hide + ")").attr("colspan", "")
        //check td which has select option
        $("tr td[data-column*=" + $(this).text() + "]").show()
      } else {
        //hide the th
        $(this).hide();
      }
    })
  } else {
    //show 2nd tr > ths 
    $("table tr:eq(1) th ").show()
    //show all td which is > 4
    $("tr").find("td:gt(4)").show()
    //add colspan again
    $("tr:eq(0)").find("th:gt(4)").attr("colspan", "2")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">
  <select id="myInput" name="packages" onchange="filter()" title="Search for Package...">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Package</option>
    <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
    <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
    <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
    <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
    <option value="VIP">VIP</option>
    <option value="Dearest">Dearest</option>
    <option value="Once In A Lifetime">Once In A Lifetime</option>
  </select>
  <select id="myInput1" name="nights" onchange="filter()" title="Search for Number of Nights">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Nights</option>
    <option value="3">3 Nights</option>
    <option value="4">4 Nights</option>
    <option value="5">5 Nights</option>
  </select>
  <select id="myInput2" name="people" onchange="filter()" title="Search for number of People..">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select People</option>
    <option value="1">1 Person</option>
    <option value="2">2 People</option>
    <option value="3">3 People</option>
    <option value="4">4 People</option>
  </select>
  <select id="myInput3" name="view" onchange="filter1()" title="Select View">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select View</option>
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
    <option value="Each">Each</option>
    <option value="Total">Total</option>
  </select>
  <table id="mytab1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">PACKAGE</th>
        <th rowspan="2">NIGHTS</th>
        <th rowspan="2">PEOPLE</th>
        <th rowspan="2">RAW</th>
        <th rowspan="2">SD</th>
        <th colspan="2">20</th>
        <th colspan="2">21</th>
        <th colspan="2">22</th>
        <th colspan="2">23</th>
        <th colspan="2">24</th>
        <th colspan="2">25</th>
        <th colspan="2">26</th>
        <th colspan="2">27</th>
        <th colspan="2">28</th>
        <th colspan="2">29</th>
        <th colspan="2">30</th>
        <th colspan="2">31</th>
        <th colspan="2">32</th>
        <th colspan="2">33</th>
        <th colspan="2">34</th>
        <th colspan="2">35</th>
        <th colspan="2">36</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!-- added class here-->
        <th class="20">Each</th>
        <th class="20">Total</th>
        <th class="21">Each</th>
        <th class="21">Total</th>
        <th class="22">Each</th>
        <th class="22">Total</th>
        <th class="23">Each</th>
        <th class="23">Total</th>
        <th class="24">Each</th>
        <th class="24">Total</th>
        <th class="25">Each</th>
        <th class="25">Total</th>
        <th class="26">Each</th>
        <th class="26">Total</th>
        <th class="27">Each</th>
        <th class="27">Total</th>
        <th class="28">Each</th>
        <th class="28">Total</th>
        <th class="29">Each</th>
        <th class="29">Total</th>
        <th class="30">Each</th>
        <th class="30">Total</th>
        <th class="31">Each</th>
        <th class="31">Total</th>
        <th class="32">Each</th>
        <th class="32">Total</th>
        <th class="33">Each</th>
        <th class="33">Total</th>
        <th class="34">Each</th>
        <th class="34">Total</th>
        <th class="35">Each</th>
        <th class="35">Total</th>
        <th class="36">Each</th>
        <th class="36">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr>    <td data-column="Package">  Bronze  </td>   <td data-column="Nights">   3   </td>   <td data-column="People">   1   </td>   <td data-column="RAW">  Not Inc </td>   <td data-column="SD">   Not Inc </td>   <td data-column="WM20 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM20 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM21 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM21 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM22 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM22 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM23 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM23 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM24 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM24 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM25 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM25 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM26 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM26 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM27 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM27 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM28 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM28 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM29 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM29 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM30 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM30 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM31 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM31 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM32 Each">    $1,225  </td>   <td data-column="WM32 Total">   $1,225  </td>   <td data-column="WM33 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM33 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM34 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM34 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM35 Each">    $2,080  </td>   <td data-column="WM35 Total">   $2,080  </td>   <td data-column="WM36 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM36 Total">   --  </td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td data-column="Package">  Bronze  </td>   <td data-column="Nights">   3   </td>   <td data-column="People">   2   </td>   <td data-column="RAW">  Not Inc </td>   <td data-column="SD">   Not Inc </td>   <td data-column="WM20 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM20 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM21 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM21 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM22 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM22 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM23 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM23 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM24 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM24 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM25 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM25 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM26 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM26 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM27 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM27 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM28 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM28 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM29 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM29 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM30 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM30 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM31 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM31 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM32 Each">    $775    </td>   <td data-column="WM32 Total">   $1,550  </td>   <td data-column="WM33 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM33 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM34 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM34 Total">   --  </td>   <td data-column="WM35 Each">    $1,475  </td>   <td data-column="WM35 Total">   $2,950  </td>   <td data-column="WM36 Each">    --  </td>   <td data-column="WM36 Total">   --  </td>   </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there since you've got a @media query already in your jsfiddle example. You can override the widths of your inputs in order to make them full-width on smaller screens.

Try adding something like this to the bottom of your @media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), 
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
   
    /* add the following below the other styles in the media query: */
    #myInput,
    #myInput1,
    #myInput2,
    #myInput3 {
        width: 100%; /* make the input full width */
        margin-bottom: 5px; /* optional: add some spacing between the vertical inputs */
    }

}
```